# How to access the string in brackets used in parametrized pytest tests?

Tags: python, pytest

When I have a parametrized `pytest` test like in the following case:

```
@parametrize('repetition', range(3))
@parametrize('name', ['test', '42'])
@parametrize('number', [3,7,54])
def test_example(repetition, name, number):
    assert 1 = 1
```

the test runner prints out lines like follows:

```
tests\test_example.py:12: test_example[1-test-7]
```

where the parametrized values show up in the rectangular bracket next to the test functions name (`test_example[0]`). How can I access the content of the rectangular bracket (i.e. the string `0`) inside the test? I have looked at the [`request`](http://pytest.org/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.python.FixtureRequest.node)
fixture, but could not find a suitable method for my needs.

To be clear: Inside the test method, I want to print the string `1-test-7`, which pytest prints on the console.

How can I access the string `1-test-7`, which `pytest` print out during a test?

I do not want to create this string by myself using something like

```
print str(repetition)+"-"+name+"-"+str(number)
```

since this would change every time I add a new parametrized argument to the test method.

In addition, if more complex objects are used in the parametrize list (like namedtuple), these objects are just references by a shortcut (e.g. `object1`, `object2`, ...).

**Addendum**: If I use the `request` fixture as an argument in my test method, I 'see' the string I would like to access when I use the following command

```
print request.keywords.node.__repr__()
```

which prints out something like

```
<Function 'test_example[2-test-3]'>
```

I am trying to find out how this method `__repr__` is defined, in order to access directly the string `test_example[2-test-3]` from which I easily can extract the string I want, `2-test-3` in this example.

Comment: Isn't that just `repetition`?

Comment: In this easy example - yes. But I have more complex examples in which I use many different parametrized arguments. Instead of creating this string myself by doing something like `str(repetition)+"_"+name+"_"+answer+"_"+str(number)`... I want to somehow get it from pytest itself, without creating a long and cumbersome string by myself...

Comment: So what's the question then? How can pytest automagically create some completely custom strings for you? I'd say it cannot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution makes use of the built-in `request` fixture which can be accessed as follows:

```
def test_example(repetition, name, number, request):
    s = request.keywords.node.name
    print s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]
```

which will print the parameter string for each single parametrized test, so each parametrized test can be identified.